# Questions you want answered at AES?

Tags: aes, community, product-research, pro-tools

OK. So, I did something like this last year, and might as well offer it up again for those of you who can't make it to AES.

Anyone have any questions for any of the vendors in the exhibit? If you see something new and want more information, or if there's something you've been wanting answered for a while now...post it here or (after Tuesday) shoot me an e-mail [here](http://www.dynamicinterference.com/contact-page/).

Yes, I fully expect Avid to announce Pro Tools 10 (or in the very least, 9.1) at the show. Do me a favor on that topic though, and wait until they've delivered their presentation on Thursday night before sending me questions about that one. ;)

***Edit:** Now that it's officially announced, and we've been told some of the features...What are your questions/complaints for Avid regarding Pro Tools 10. I've got my own list that I've generated already, but I'm sure some of you may think of something that I haven't.*

*...As far as complaints, I already plan to hit them over the pricing disparity regarding HD upgrades (versions 7, 8 and 9).*

Comment: That's such a great idea! 

Comment: @Shaun One thing that I have not been able to 100 percent confirm is the Zaxcom Nomads ability in its "Current" State to record at sample rates above 48k.  I know according to threads it is supposed to be able to, and the software simulator has the option to change sample rate to 192k but zaxcom and distributors do not have that listed as an actual specification on their websites, currently only 44.1, 47.952, 48, 48.048.  I'm seriously considering getting one of these instead of a 744/442 combo and the sample rate is the make or break it factor for me.

Answer (score 4):

Sound Devices

Have they ever considered designing a small stereo recorder with built-in mics and XLR inputs?

Comment: will ask...at least they'll learn that there's some interest if they haven't.

Comment: good question, maybe like their PXT recorders except without the video... and maybe with WIFI so you can wirelessly remote them from iPhone (eg if using multiple recorders)

Comment: Plus one on that question. I've always wondered why Sound Devices has entered the hand held recorder game. They'd do it better than anybody.

Comment: And another question for the SD folks. Can we get a 744 with four mic pres please?

Comment: RE: 4 mic pres on the 744. I asked them this very question last year. The answer I got was that the price point didn't make sense for them. The price of adding 2 more pres to a 744 isn't that far off from making the 788t they said.

Answer (score 4):

Answers to these questions:

**Zaxcom Nomad** - up to 96kHz confirmed

**Sound Devices handheld** - short answer, no. long answer, they don't want to be a "me too" company, so they would need to consider what can they bring to it that is unique. they also want to continue catering to the higher end market. if they did try to put one together, it would be a question of price-point vs. demand.

**Sennheiser MKH8030** - yes. they want to, and will do it. they wanted to concentrate on getting the shotgun mics out, which they have. it's one of the next things in the queue. as for target date...there isn't one. so don't expect it anytime soon.

**Other handhelds** - haven't seen anything. i don't even think any vendors on the floor have the new roland ones, but i'll check those out if i spot them.

**DVTK to CPTK upgrade path** - will return to the store. they're changing the CPTK (i.e. no longer including Neyrinck), so the store is being updated as well. expect it to return soon, but no date was given.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to know if anything comes out in the portable HH recorder category that competes with either the D50 or the Marantz PDM661.

Something in the $500-$800 range with killer pre-s and good battery life.

Comment: i'll keep my eye out and see if i can spot any worth testing out on the floor.

Answer (score 2):

Sennheiser MKH 8030 ;)

Comment: ahh...the ever-present question. lol

Comment: video their response.... be good to hear the reasons for delay from the horses mouth!

Comment: Plus a thousand on that one. My MKH8040 is lonely.

Answer (score 1):

Question to Avid.  Why did you just screw over every DVTK and MPTK owner whose stuck without an upgrade path?

Comment: yep, put that question on my list last night. will definitely be hounding them on that one.

Comment: Again for Avid.  Why can you only upgrade the software for an HD core card once?  

Answer (score 0):

Another question for Avid (unless it's been covered somewhere and I've just missed it).

With a new HDX Pro Tools Rig, can you use AAX Native and AAX DSP plugs together in the same session, like you could use TDM and RTAS together with the previous HD Systems?

And if you can, does this still use up voices when you switch from one to another?

Cheers

Comment: didn't see this one in time, but i'll stop by and ask tomorrow if i get a chance. going to do a post on designing sound right now on information i collected today though.

Comment: the answers to your questions are: yes, and yes. native and dsp together in a session, native after dsp will eat up two additional voices (just like RTAS after TDM)